# Display active document in IE through my Protocol Handler

Tags: c#, protocol-handler

The protocol handler I have implemented using pluggable protocol interfaces of IE is rendering HTML files pretty well in IE. The next step is being able to render active documents such as doc, ppt, pdf, etc in IE through the protocol handler. I understand I need to implement some interfaces for that but I am not sure of what exactly has to be done. Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to report MIME type properly to IE.
Are you taking over HTTP/HTTPS, or creating a new protocol?

Comment: I am creating a new protocol handler of my own (using the asynchronous pluggable protocol API for urlmon.dll) and reporting the mime type using BINDSTATUS_MIMETYPEAVAILABLE. But still even after the entire data is read by urlmon.dll from my protocol handler, data isn't rendered.

Comment: As I replied to you another question, please study my tp:// implementation and you'll see that it does render various files properly.